# Updates certain values only if a matching int flag is received

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an `object` class that tells me what type of data has changed.

```
object Part {
    const val CONTRAST      = 0x00000001
    const val SATURATION    = 0x00000010
    const val PIXELATION    = 0x00000100
    const val SHARPNESS     = 0x00001000
    const val BRIGHTNESS    = 0x00010000
    const val ALL           = 0x11111111
}
```

In my usage method I check what `Part` of data has changed. And, update only matched data.

```
fun applyUpdate(flag: Int, percentage: Int) {

    if (flag and Part.CONTRAST == flag) {
        applyContrastUpdate(percentage)
    }

    if (flag and Part.SATURATION == flag) {
        applySaturationUpdate(percentage)
    }

    .
    .
}

// applyUpdate(Part.CONTRAST, 60)    --> only contrast is updated.
// applyUpdate(Part.SATURATION, 30)  --> only saturation is updated.
// applyUpdate{Part.ALL, 0}.         --> all values are updated.
```

What I understand is that `0x0001 and 0x0001 = 0x0001` = CONTRAST.

But, if I define a new `Part` say `DISTORTION = 0x0011`, then changes in distortion will also change CONTRAST.

e.g. `0x0011 and 0x0001 = 0x0001` = CONTRAST

With this code, I can define upto 8 `Part`s. Placing `1`'s properly. Right? If I had 36 `Part`s, how can I keep this functionality working?

Comment: You might be better of using an enum or do you need the ability to add them because `0x0011` is CONTRAST and SATURATION

Comment: Yes, I need that ability. I want to say {UpdateAll, UpdateOnlyThese, UpdateOnlyThis} to `applyUpdate(Int)` method.

Comment: Off-topic, then you can't use equal (==)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Should I use EnumSets https://eddmann.com/posts/using-bit-flags-and-enumsets-in-java/

Comment: Enum in combination with EnumSets looks like a good solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EnumSets are probably less error-prone than bit flags. It's a matter of opinion, but I think the syntax is easier to work with for bit flags. Bit flags like this can be used for optimization. In Android, the designers were very enum-averse, so enums are not used in platform code.

If you do go with flags:

You can have up to 31 flags, not 8. Or 63 flags if you use `Long` instead of `Int`. (Not 32 and 64, because the very first bit is used for sign.) You've defined your constants using hexadecimal, not binary, and only using one possible value of each hexadecimal digit, so you've only used a quarter of your available bits.

You can define them using doubling values in each digit, up to 8:

```
object Part {
    const val CONTRAST      = 0x00000001
    const val SATURATION    = 0x00000002
    const val PIXELATION    = 0x00000004
    const val SHARPNESS     = 0x00000008
    const val BRIGHTNESS    = 0x00000010
    const val SOMETHING     = 0x00000020
    const val ALL           = 0x0000003F
}
```

When you check `flag and Part.CONTRAST == flag`, you are checking if the flag has *only* `CONTRAST` turned on. If you want to check if the flag merely *contains* `CONTRAST`, you would check `flag and Part.CONTRAST == Part.CONTRAST`, or to put it more succinctly: `flag and Part.CONTRAST != 0`.

Comment: Hi, do you have an article or reference where I can read about how `0x0000003F` can contain all of above? I had no idea that I could use these values as well. But, remembering how 0xFFFF0000 works as a color, I think you are right. But, I still don't know how `ALL = 0x0000003F` contains CONTRAST, SATURATION, etc.

Comment: Also, what would you have used in Android? Flags or EnumSet.

Comment: `3F` is the sum of those hexadecimal numbers. Hexadecimal is base 16, so each digit goes from 0 to F (15) instead of 0 to 9, and the addition is done the same way as with traditional base 10 numbers. The sum of 1, 2, 4, and 8 is F (15). That's the first digit on the right. The next digit is the sum of 1 and 2.

Comment: I think flags are easier to work with, but if I am going to serialize it, I use EnumSet to make it more future-proof. From reading a little about it, it seems like there are some people at Google that are convinced enums really cause a performance hit and others who think that's ridiculous. I think someone showed through a certain type of benchmark that there could be a performance hit. I think these concerns are moot at this point. Modern Android phones are orders of magnitude more powerful than the early ones.

Comment: Oh, to answer your question, the hexadecimal sum equals the binary combination of all those values because of how the math works out when you choose values that are all powers of two. In binary, a number that is a 1 followed by zeros is a power of two.